# While setting up a SPFx solution, getting node:path error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, error, gulp

- Node version - 12.22.12
- Npm version - 6.14.16
- SPFx version - 1.12.1
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.17.4

After `npm i`, when running `Gulp build`, its giving error as:

> Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'

> requireStack: [
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\rush-lib\dist\rush-lib.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\rush-lib\lib\index.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\spfx-heft-plugins\lib\plugins\devDeployPlugin\SpDevDeploy.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\spfx-heft-plugins\lib\index.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-core-tasks\lib\webpack\ConfigureWebpackTask.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-core-tasks\lib\index.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js',
> 'C:\Users\Documents\gulpfile.js',
> 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js',
> 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js',
> 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js',
> 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js'
> ]

Comment: Could you include your package.json file in the question and perhaps any steps you've already tried to resolve the error, like deleting node_modules folder and running npm install again? If I'm not overlooking anything the versions you use for NodeJs, npm and SPFx should be working just fine when you compare them to the SPFx dev environment compatibility list here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the package.json file in your project, do you see line like this:

```
"engines": {
"node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0 || >=18.17.1 <19.0.0"},
```

If you do, then you need to upgrade node version, but not the newest version, but the version that is allowed by this formula, i.e. 18.17.2